# AWS EMR Hive fails due to serde2/serde

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, emr, hive-serde

I am running EMR hive query on S3 and it fails saying "Map operator initialization failed"

I tried to set `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` as below, still no luck.

```
set HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/usr/lib/hive/lib/*;
```

Also, adding below jar,

`add jar /usr/hive/json-serde-1.3.7-jar-with-dependencies.jar` . This jar file is present at the given path.

I am not sure why it is complaining as below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/SerDe
```

The log is as below:

> Status: Failed
>       Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 10, vertexId=vertex_1515176779844_0076_2_02, diagnostics=[Task failed,
>   taskId=task_1515176779844_0076_2_02_000031, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0
>   failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) :
>   attempt_1515176779844_0076_2_02_000031_0:java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:211)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:168)
>         at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:370)
>         at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
>         at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
>         at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
>         at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
>         at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>       Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:354)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:184)
>         ... 14 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/SerDe
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
>         at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>         at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2134)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2099)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.PartitionDesc.getDeserializer(PartitionDesc.java:177)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.getConvertedOI(MapOperator.java:295)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.setChildren(MapOperator.java:420)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:286)
>         ... 15 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDe
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>         ... 35 more
>       ], TaskAttempt 1 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) :
>   attempt_1515176779844_0076_2_02_000031_1:java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:211)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:168)
>         at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:370)
>         at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
>         at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
>         at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
>         at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
>         at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>       Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:354)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:184)
>         ... 14 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/SerDe
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
>         at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>         at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2134)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2099)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.PartitionDesc.getDeserializer(PartitionDesc.java:177)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.getConvertedOI(MapOperator.java:295)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.setChildren(MapOperator.java:420)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:286)
>         ... 15 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDe
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>         ... 35 more
>       ], TaskAttempt 2 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) :
>   attempt_1515176779844_0076_2_02_000031_2:java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:211)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:168)
>         at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:370)
>         at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
>         at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
>         at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
>         at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
>         at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>       Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:354)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:184)
>         ... 14 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/SerDe
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
>         at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>         at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2134)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2099)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.PartitionDesc.getDeserializer(PartitionDesc.java:177)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.getConvertedOI(MapOperator.java:295)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.setChildren(MapOperator.java:420)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:286)
>         ... 15 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDe
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>         ... 35 more
>       ], TaskAttempt 3 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) :
>   attempt_1515176779844_0076_2_02_000031_3:java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:211)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:168)
>         at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:370)
>         at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
>         at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
>         at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
>         at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
>         at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>       Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:354)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:184)
>         ... 14 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/SerDe
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
>         at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>         at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2134)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2099)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.PartitionDesc.getDeserializer(PartitionDesc.java:177)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.getConvertedOI(MapOperator.java:295)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.setChildren(MapOperator.java:420)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:286)
>         ... 15 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDe
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>         ... 35 more
>       ]], Vertex did not succeed due to OWN_TASK_FAILURE, failedTasks:1 killedTasks:159, Vertex vertex_1515176779844_0076_2_02 [Map 10]
>   killed/failed due to:OWN_TASK_FAILURE]
>       Vertex killed, vertexName=Reducer 7, vertexId=vertex_1515176779844_0076_2_04, diagnostics=[Vertex received
>   Kill while in RUNNING state., Vertex did not succeed due to
>   OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE, failedTasks:0 killedTasks:12, Vertex
>   vertex_1515176779844_0076_2_04 [Reducer 7] killed/failed due
>   to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]
>       Vertex killed, vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_1515176779844_0076_2_06, diagnostics=[Vertex received
>   Kill while in RUNNING state., Vertex did not succeed due to
>   OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE, failedTasks:0 killedTasks:1, Vertex
>   vertex_1515176779844_0076_2_06 [Reducer 2] killed/failed due
>   to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]
>       Vertex killed, vertexName=Reducer 4, vertexId=vertex_1515176779844_0076_2_08, diagnostics=[Vertex received
>   Kill while in RUNNING state., Vertex did not succeed due to
>   OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE, failedTasks:0 killedTasks:7, Vertex
>   vertex_1515176779844_0076_2_08 [Reducer 4] killed/failed due
>   to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]
>       Vertex killed, vertexName=Reducer 3, vertexId=vertex_1515176779844_0076_2_07, diagnostics=[Vertex received
>   Kill while in RUNNING state., Vertex did not succeed due to
>   OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE, failedTasks:0 killedTasks:7, Vertex
>   vertex_1515176779844_0076_2_07 [Reducer 3] killed/failed due
>   to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]
>       Vertex killed, vertexName=Reducer 5, vertexId=vertex_1515176779844_0076_2_10, diagnostics=[Vertex received
>   Kill while in RUNNING state., Vertex did not succeed due to
>   OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE, failedTasks:0 killedTasks:14, Vertex
>   vertex_1515176779844_0076_2_10 [Reducer 5] killed/failed due
>   to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]
>       Vertex killed, vertexName=Reducer 11, vertexId=vertex_1515176779844_0076_2_09, diagnostics=[Vertex received
>   Kill while in RUNNING state., Vertex did not succeed due to
>   OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE, failedTasks:0 killedTasks:12, Vertex
>   vertex_1515176779844_0076_2_09 [Reducer 11] killed/failed due
>   to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]
>       Vertex killed, vertexName=Map 6, vertexId=vertex_1515176779844_0076_2_03, diagnostics=[Vertex received
>   Kill while in RUNNING state., Vertex did not succeed due to
>   OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE, failedTasks:0 killedTasks:165, Vertex
>   vertex_1515176779844_0076_2_03 [Map 6] killed/failed due
>   to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]
>       Vertex killed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1515176779844_0076_2_05, diagnostics=[Vertex received
>   Kill while in RUNNING state., Vertex did not succeed due to
>   OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE, failedTasks:0 killedTasks:139, Vertex
>   vertex_1515176779844_0076_2_05 [Map 1] killed/failed due
>   to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]
>       DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:8
>       FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Vertex failed,
>   vertexName=Map 10, vertexId=vertex_1515176779844_0076_2_02,
>   diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1515176779844_0076_2_02_000031,
>   diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Error while running
>   task ( failure ) :
>   attempt_1515176779844_0076_2_02_000031_0:java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:211)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:168)
>         at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:370)
>         at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
>         at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
>         at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
>         at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
>         at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>       Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:354)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:184)
>         ... 14 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/SerDe
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
>         at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>         at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2134)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2099)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.PartitionDesc.getDeserializer(PartitionDesc.java:177)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.getConvertedOI(MapOperator.java:295)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.setChildren(MapOperator.java:420)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:286)
>         ... 15 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDe
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>         ... 35 more
>       ], TaskAttempt 1 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) :
>   attempt_1515176779844_0076_2_02_000031_1:java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed